# Use indexer to cast batched input tensor into different Sequentials

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, tensor, indexer

I'm having troubles in the following scenario:

Suppose we have an indexer tensor (or vector for that case) that, for example, contains these values: `tensor([0,1,1,0])`. Also, let's suppose I have a batch of equal length (4) of input tensors, each of length 64: `tensor([[foo],[bar],[tee],[aaa]])`.

Based on the numbers specified by the indexer tensor, I need to collect the corresponding input tensors. That is, for index `0` we have `tensor([foo], [aaa])` and for index `1` we have `tensor([bar],[tee])`.

This is because I now have to feed each "group" of inputs to a different Sequential net whose structure is not relevant here. The point is that each of these two Sequentials will give outputs `output_0` for index `0`'s inputs, and `output_1` for index `1`'s inputs. The outputs are as such: `tensor([output_foo], [output_aaa])` and `tensor([output_bar],[output_tee])`, respectively.

The last step is, using the indexer tensor from the beginning, join all the output tensors back into one, that is, `tensor([output_foo], [output_bar],[output_tee], [output_aaa])`, while *preserving gradient*.

I tried doing this with for-loops, that is, looping first for index `0`, then for `1`, and inside each iteration I collected the corresponding inputs, and got the corresponding outputs. I then had to mix it all up with yet *another* for loop. But the thing is, although the successive output tensors from each iteration have each their own gradient function, the final tensor doesn't. That means *I'm crashing gradient* here, and I suspect it is beacuse of the use of loops.

My question is, **is there a way to achieve this *without using for-loops*?**. I have the idea that using the indexer tensor and maybe some boolean masks would do the job in a sort-of matricial manner, but I still can't visualize what it would look like in real code.

Here's a minimal example:

```
B = 5   # batch size
F = 64  # feature dimension

outputs = torch.zeros((B), requires_grad=True)

indexer = torch.argmax(masks, dim=1) # (B,) int
for idx in indexer.unique():
    mask = (indexer == idx) # (B,) bool
    curr_inputs = torch.masked_select(inputs, mask.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1,F)).view(-1,F) # (b, F), only the entries for idx

    # Apply the appropiate Sequential to each input according to its original index
    curr_outputs = apply_to_sequential_by_idx(curr_inputs, idx)

    # Join back together the outputs to get back to shape (B,)
    j=0
    for i, index in enumerate(indexer):
        if idx == index:
            outputs.data[i].copy_(curr_outputs.data[j])
            j+=1

return outputs # Gradient is lost here (no grad_fn)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example with a loop?

Comment: @Ivan see if what I have added to the main body of the question is helpful